# How does TAILS manage to start tor automatically?

Tags: tails, startup

I want `tor` to run continuously as soon as I am connected.

**How does TAILS  manage to start tor automatically?**

Answer (score 1):

It's installed as a system service, the same way as is defined [here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en#ubuntu).

It's started automatically at boot by systemd, the system service manager.

Tails also has extensive configuration and tweaks for it to use Tor properly, simply installing Tor won't provide the same features but it will start automatically when the operating system starts.

Comment: `update-rc.d tor defaults; echo "service tor start" >> /etc/rc.local` is not enough. `service tor restart` has to be launched if I disconnect and then reconnect to the Internet.

Comment: Unlikely to be related to service management, it should just start itself so I'm not sure why you're messing with `/etc/rc.local`? What kind of internet connection are you using?